# How Can I Fetch Sub Category From Rest Api(Restkit) Using Expandable Tableview Cell Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

This is method for cellforrow when i try to fetch category and subcategory using restkit , category fetch suceesfully but  whenever i try to fetch sub category i found fatal error: Index out of range.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

```
    let section = getSectionIndex(indexPath.row)
    let row = getRowIndex(indexPath.row)


    if row == 0
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! Menu1
        cell.lbl.text = data[section].name!
        cell.btn.tag = section
        cell.btn.setImage(sections[section].collapsed! ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "right"):#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Down"), for: UIControlState())
        cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MenuViewController.toggleCollapse), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2") as! MenuTableViewCell!
        cell?.lbl.text = sections[section].items[row - 1]
        cell?.myimg.image = sections[section].img1[row - 1]
        cell?.lbl.textColor = UIColor.gray
     //  cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Swiss721BT-Roman", size: 8)
        cell?.lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)


        return cell!
    }
}
```

number of rows in sections what should i change for fatal error:index out of range
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {

```
    if section == 0
    {
        return 0

    }

    // For section 1, the total count is items count plus the number of headers
    var count = sections.count

    //var sapna = data[section]

    for section in sections
    {
        //count += data.count
      count += section.items.count

       //count += section.items.append(contentsOf: sapna.slug!)

    }
    return data.count
}
```

[Image for category and Sub- category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SQSc.png)

Comment: Don't post pictures of code or links to pictures of code. Put it right in your question/

Comment: thank u for yr suggestion